# Remove Element from PSCmdlet Parameter Array

Tags: powershell

I'm currently checking parameters passed into my script using:

```
$CommandName = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
$ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameters
$Values = Get-Variable -Name $ParameterList.Values.Name -EA SilentlyContinue
```

This works fine. Now I want to remove specific elements, so I create a collection:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = $Values
```

And call the remove method:

```
$Array = $Array.Remove('TestParameter')
```

Outputting `$Array` now returns nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Array.Remove('TestParameter')` doesn't return the array.  It just removes the first item that matches.

Try:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = $Values
$Array.Remove('TestParameter')
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = @(1,1,2,3,5,8)
PS C:\> $Array.Remove(1)
PS C:\> $Array
1
2
3
5
8
```

Note that only the *first* matching value is removed by the `Remove()` function, so be aware of how it works with duplicates.

However, as presented, your code is not going to work because Parameters is a HashTable, not an Array.  HashTables sometimes aren't treated as IEnumerable, so sometimes a HashTable will not always be treated as a collection but as a single object.  It's a quirk of HashTables.  This means that `Get-Variable` isn't seeing that it's getting a whole array of names, and instead thinks it's just getting one name that has carriage returns in it.

Try this:

```
$ParameterList = @((Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameters.Keys)
$Values = Get-Variable -Name $ParameterList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = $Values
$Array.Remove('TestParameter')
$Array
```

---

You can check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.remove?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_ArrayList_Remove_System_Object_), or you can view the function definitions with PowerShell directly:

```
PS C:\> ,$x | Get-Member | Where-Object Name -eq 'Remove'


   TypeName: System.Collections.ArrayList

Name   MemberType Definition
----   ---------- ----------
Remove Method     void Remove(System.Object obj), void IList.Remove(System.Object value)
```

See how both definitions start with `void`?  That means the method has no return value.  Note the comma in `,$x` is there to get the arraylist object itself instead of the underlying items in the arraylist.

Comment: If you try this with the `System.Array` from `$ParameterList = (Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameters` you will see it does not work?

Comment: @Jelphy `(Get-Command -Name $CommandName).Parameters` is a HashTable, not an array, and it's causing issues.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get only parameters not matching `'TestParameter'`:

```
$Array = $Array | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'TestParameter' }
```

You cannot remove an item from a fixed width collection, you have to create a selection of the items you need and overwrite the old collection (`$Array` in your example).